# Add Emails to a Database when Received (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, email

I want to make it so users can automatically subscribe to my mailing list by sending a email with a special body.

Example:
Send "subscribe" to "email@mywebsite.com" and a PHP script is automatically executed to add them to a database.

Send "unsubscribe" to "email@mywebsite.com" and the PHP script removes them.

I have the script to add/remove them done easily, but what I need help with is how to actually implant the email receive to execute the function...If that makes sense.

Using cPanel/WHM, can do a cron job.

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: It's called email piping and not really to do with coding as much as system administration.

Comment: My setup requires a custom script. This is not for emails directly - it's for text messages. Users can text the email to sub/unsub to updates. It uses a custom software I'm working on.

Comment: Email piping has nothing to do with the end user.  It is set up in the mail server to direct an email address to an executable and can be configured on CPanel.  The other way would be running a cron and logging into a mail server every so often and parsing all the unread emails.  This can be done with any IMAP extension.  One is instant and doesn't require cron, one requires cron and is probably easier for remote mail servers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be the following code (i didn't check it):

```
if( $imap ) { 

     //Check no.of.msgs 
     $num = imap_num_msg($imap); 

     //if there is a message in your inbox 
     if( $num >0 ) { 
          //read that mail recently arrived 
          if (imap_qprint(imap_headerinfo($imap, $num)) == 'subscribe'){
            // code for add user to database
          };

          if (imap_qprint(imap_headerinfo($imap, $num)) == 'unsubscribe'){
            // code for delete user to database
          }



     } 

     //close the stream 
     imap_close($imap); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: How do I "connect" the email server with this php script? Thanks for your help.